# c++: How to catch mouse clicks wherever they happen

Tags: c++, winapi, mouse

I am stuck with an application I am writing where I need to monitor for mouse clicks.

The clicks may happen anywhere on the screen and not inside the app window, and for each click I must pass a message (perform an action or something).

I looked around and read some suggestions like using

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
```

but I was unsuccessful.

Does anyone have an idea on how to implement what I need?

Comment: You can use a hook: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: There seem to a lot of people doing global keyboard and mouse hooks recently, I wonder what they all want them for...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to set a mouse hook as described in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Note that in your case the hook would need to be global. This means that you need to implement a handler function in a DLL, which will be loaded into all processes in the system which receive mouse message. Such DLL will communicate with your main application using some interprocess communication (IPC) mechanism like shared memory or via Windows messages *posted* (not sent) from the DLL to the main application.

You can use the source code from [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/67091/Mouse-and-KeyBoard-Hooking-utility-with-VC) as a guide.

Update: as per Chris' correction, I should note that above applies to "regular" mouse hook which is synchronous. Low-level hook doesn't need to be located in the DLL, but it has certain limitations which are described in the [corresponding MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: You don't need a dll if you use a low level one. I can confirm that from experience.

Comment: @chris and where did I write about low-level hook?

Comment: You didn't. I was suggesting it due to the greatly less amount of work needed to get it working.

Comment: @Chris Low-level hooks have an unpleasant drawback of time limit, which make it hard for a novice to manage right especially when time-consuming operation is involved. It might be easier to deal with a DLL. I agree with you that Low-level hook might be fine for quick-and-dirty tests or simple activity.

Comment: I see your point. I come from writing many of those "quick-and-dirty tests", so I'm used to just getting it working without wasting so much time on it.

Comment: With any sort of hook - low-level or otherwise - it's still good practice to keep the work in the hook *minimal*. Just do whatever basic triage/testing you need to do on the coordinates, and then post a message back to (or otherwise communicate with) the app mainline to let it know there's work do do. LL hooks do have one major advantage for the novice which is they avoid having to set up some out-of-proc communication mechanism; you can use global variables as-is - and they work across 32/64-bit, whereas inproc hooks require 32bit vs 64bit to be dealt with separately.

Comment: @BrendanMcK Hook itself should be minimal of course, but in case of OP's task the hook would just notify the main code that some job needs to be done.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp; agree; I really just pointing out that with decently written code, the time limit for a LL hook shouldn't be an issue. (If someone's hitting that, they're doing hooks wrong in the first place!) My take is that in-proc can have better perf, but is trickier to write due to cross-proc issues; whereas LL has more overhead, but is far simpler to get up and running. For a novice, I'd recommend starting with a LL hook to play with the hook in the first place - otherwise with a separate DLL, they'll be spending quite some time figuring out the cross-proc stuff.

Answer (score 6):

well I don't really know if you solved your problem. I hope so.
But I was in the same trouble today and searching I found a way really easy to do it.

So here you are:

```
int keyPressed(int key){
    return (GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x8000 != 0);
}

int main(){
    while(1){
        if(keyPressed(VK_LBUTTON)){
            printf("%s\n","Click izquierdo");
        }
        if(keyPressed(VK_RBUTTON)){
            printf("%s\n","Click Derecho");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the key of this solution is the function GetAsyncKeyState(key), where key anyone of the codes that appears here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 5):

You could use `SetWindowsHookEx`

Here's a small sample:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#include <windows.h>

HHOOK MouseHook;

LRESULT CALLBACK MouseHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){

        PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT k = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)(lParam);
        POINT p;


        if(wParam == WM_RBUTTONDOWN)
        { 
          // right button clicked 
          GetCursorPos(&p);
        }

}

void StayAlive(){
        while(_getch() != 27) { }
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
        LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd){
        FreeConsole();

        MouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL,MouseHookProc,hInstance,0);
        StayAlive();

        UnhookWindowsHookEx(MouseHook);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Curious, does this work? LL hooks require a message loop, and I can't recall offhand if _getch() pumps messages behind the scenes to allow the messages to get delivered - most console-style API's don't. MessageBox() is another quick and dirty alternative to use that definitely pumps messages and is useful when playing with these APIs initially.

Comment: Doing `GetCursorPos` within the mouse, hook is uneeded. The `lParam` is an address to a `MSLLHOOKSTRUCT` which contains a field `pt` which has the point info.

Comment: E0167 argument of type "LRESULT (__stdcall OpenCVApp::*)(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)" is incompatible with parameter of type "HOOKPROC"

Answer (score 2):

`LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(...)`, as it name suggests is a (specific) window (message) processor where you can analyze and respond to messages on the queue that were deferred by the system to your custom definition of the callback for further processing.

Since you want to detect and act on mouse clicks anywhere on the screen, as chris suggested in the comments, one way is to hook yourself into the system by calling SetWindowsHookEx() which is quite verbose in its very definition - it allows you to track stuff happening on the system and relay that information back to your application.

This is the syntax which you need to employ in order to get yourself

```
HHOOK WINAPI SetWindowsHookEx(
  __in  int idHook,
  __in  HOOKPROC lpfn,
  __in  HINSTANCE hMod,
  __in  DWORD dwThreadId
);
```

It takes in a specific hook id, which are basically little #defines which tell the function what kind of messages you wish to receive from all over the system, you pass it a callback just like the WndProc, but this time it's meant to process the incoming messages regarding  across the system. hMod simply refers to the handle to the application or the DLL in which the just mentioned proc function callback is located in. The last one relates to threads currently running on the system, setting this to 0 or NULL retrieves messages for all existing threads.

**Important**:

Do note that Aurus' example call to the SetWindowsHookEx is process-specific which a fancy word relating it to an actual application, instead of a DLL which can be appended to multiple processes across the system ( a global one ) and return information to your application. It would be prudent to take the time and effort to investigate Eugene's recommended method instead of this forceful approach useful only for experiments. It's a bit "harder", but the reward is worthwhile.

*Less work is not always better or preferable.*

Comment: Aurus's example is not actually process-specific: Low-Level hooks (both keyboard and mouse) are unlike other hooks in that they run in the context of the thread that set up the hook, so don't require a separate DLL, but can still process input from all other processes/threads on the same desktop (assuming appropriate security privileges). You can filter by setting the dwThreadId, but since Aurur's example passes 0, it will get called as a result of input for any process. (...and even if you do specify a DLL for a LL hook, it won't actually get loaded into those processes.)