# Pop up window form application with C#

Tags: c#, winapi, popupwindow

I am new in C# .I dont know for sure if there is a question like that but i searched many titles but i couldn't find what i want to do.

So here is the question.

I want to do a pop up keyboard with win form C#. When i clicked textbox out of my form, that is the textbox is not in my form. For example i clicked google search textbox or other win app's textbox. My program will know it and pop up.Is there a handle or something like that in winapi that sends this information to my form application or get this information from winapi.

Thank you for your answers. And sorry if there is alreay asked in here and could not realize it.

Comment: Can you explain your use case? Seems to my like you're trying to build adware/spyware/crapware and don't know how.

Comment: This keyboard only some part of my program it will work when my program started but will not show i only want to know if clicked a textbox or something like that in window my keyboard form will show and after writing done will hide. Just i need to know that if there is a way to get information from winapi or something else.

Comment: Let me clearify your answer for the audience: "This keyboard *is* only some part of my program *-* it will work when my program started *,* but *it* will not show *;* *I* only want to know if *the user* clicked a textbox or something like that in window *.* My keyboard form will show and after writing *is* done *it* will hide. *I just* need to know *if* there is a way to get information *to do this with the* winapi or something else."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the technique you're looking for is answered in this article: [c++: How to catch mouse clicks wherever they happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817860/c-how-to-catch-mouse-clicks-wherever-they-happen).

What you would do is create a global mouse hook and use it to determine whether a user has clicked in a text box.  If they have, you can pop up your keyboard and post the completed text back to the text box. I would suggest using the clipboard to paste the keyboard text into the text box.