# How to loop properly pixel scanning using bitmaps

Tags: c#, bitmap

So here is my code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GandomTest
{
    class Program
    {
        public static bool SearchPixel(string hexcode)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as Image);
            graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);

            Color desiredPixelColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(hexcode);

            for (int x = 0; x < SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height; y++)
                {
                    Color currentPixelColor = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y);

                    if (desiredPixelColor == currentPixelColor)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("Color found!");
                        Thread.Sleep(10000);
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Not found");
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SearchPixel("#000000");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I was trying to loop the pixel recognition so as soon as the pixel is detected write something in console. The thing I do not know how can I make this work properly. I know this probably isn't the fastest way to do it but everytime I run it, and the specified color is on screen, the program does not detect it.

Comment: What happens when you step through the code with the debugger?  It should tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: Why do you switch from Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds to SystemInformation.VirtualScreen?  Use the debugger to see what the virtual screen parameters are...

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60144303/10216583) out. Might help.

Comment: @JQSOFT Could you provide the visual studio project? It seems really useful to me but I can't get it to work. Thanks by the way!

Comment: @JQSOFT But my point is to search any color within the entire screen, not just one certain point.

Comment: Yes that what it does if you remove the mentioned line. Have you tried? Just search for the color:  `if (Color.FromArgb(alpha, red, green, blue).ToArgb().Equals(targetColor.ToArgb()) { //color exists.... }`

Comment: Your code works fine here

Comment: @JQSOFT Oh okay, It seems to work now. But when referring to `var targetColor =...` What's the Color code I need to input? Hex color code?

Comment: Hello there. Should be a color like `targetColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(hexcode);` or `targetColor = Color.FromArgb(23, 93, 233);` Just of a Color structure from any source.

Comment: @JQSOFT Okay thanks, it works flawlessly but now, if I wanna keep scanning continuously after clicking the button, do I just loop it with ´ while(true) ´ or do I need to use a timer?

Comment: Why would you do that? Do you mean searching for more that one color? If so, just create a list of colors: `var targetColors = new List<Color>();`, add some colors to find, and just replace the `if` block with `if (targetColors.Any(c => c.ToArgb().Equals(Color.FromArgb(alpha, red, green, blue).ToArgb()))) { //A color exists }`

Comment: @JQSOFT No, I mean, let's say I'm waiting a random amount of time until a color appears.Then once it finds it, which it does, the program stops running. I want it to keep scanning, I thought I could do it with while(true) and so did I. But the program crashes after finding the color.

Comment: I tell you what. Edit your question to add what have you tried so far in a new `code block`  to be on the same page.  Also it will be useful to mention the finale result that you are trying to get.